# Is there a way to send a signal if something happens, and receive the signal and do something else?

Tags: python, signals

I can do it with .txt files, that when something is happening it writes "ok", and an other program reads it and do something if the .txt file has "ok" inside it. But, I would like to know if I can do with another way.

Comment: This is a bit broad as is-- can you go into some more detail? Are you trying to communicate between two Python programs, or a Python program and a program you wrote in another language, or a Python program and a program you have no control over that expects things a certain way?

Comment: Over two python programs working at the same time...

Comment: A signal that tells "do that", meaning a function... I think it's pretty simple...

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are [*inter-process communication* (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocess_communication).  Without knowing more about your application, I'd wager that you probably want some sort of pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a signal, e.g. USR1, but I don't think you can raise signals in Python.
Instead of communicating via a file as you do now you can use a named pipe. A named pipe will provide some extra functionality, see last paragraph.

You open the pipe as an ordinary file and then write and read as you do now. You create the pipe by `mkfifo filename`, can also be created in your python program. Two example programs for demo:

Sender:

```
fdw= os.open("./mypipe", os.O_WRONLY)
while (1):
 try:
    os.write(fdw, "OK\n")
 except OSError, e:
    if e.errno==errno.EPIPE:
        #Receiver closed the pipe                                                   
        print "Reader closed pipe\n"
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        #some other os problem                                                         
        print os.strerror(e.errno)
  time.sleep(3)
```

Receiver:

```
fdr= os.open("./mypipe", os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
while (1):
  try:
    s= os.read(fdr, 10)
    print s
  except OSError, e:
    if e.errno==errno.EBUSY:
        print "nothing to read yet\n"
    else:
        print os.strerror(e.errno)
  time.sleep(1)
```

The sender opens a blocking pipe, so you will get an exception if the receiver closes the pipe, usually while terminating. The reader opens a non-blocking pipe so it will not hang while waiting for anything written by the sender. Combinations of blocking/non-blocking yield different responses when sender or receiver close one pipe end. You may want to open the write end non-blocking if there are any chance of pipe overflow (kbytes written, nothing read).

Answer (score -4):

It seems you want to use a function.
I'm assuming you're doing something along the lines of doing various tests and if it is true, each one does something different...

```
def function(parameters):
```

The parameters are the objects used in the function:

```
def fib(a, b, c):
   x=a*b*c*10
   print x
```

That's just a simple function, but you can do very complex things.

I refer you to this webpage on TutorialsPoint: [Python Functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

If you have the function in another program, maybe open the file:

```
open(file_name)
function(parameters)
```

After python opens the file, just input the function as normal. This should work.

Comment: I know how to create a function, I just want it to be executed when a signal arrives from another python program...

Comment: Special -1 for TutorialsPoint.  It's full of errors. Avoid it.